# Animate an element that moves to occupy empty space with CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/kscjq0y0/

I want to animate the movement of the yellow div when the red one disappears.

I know it can be done with `jQuery animate` but I want a `CSS3` solution (even if it's not fully supported by all modern browsers).

I've tried the CSS `transition` property but doesn't seem to work for this kind of movement.

It's there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it shrink

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    
}

#bottom {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#top {
    transition: all 2s;
}
body:hover #top {
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: @vals Don't be! You beat me to the punch :) Yours has a better demo quality anyways, using pseudo class hover instead of a jQuery timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, by modifying the CSS attribute that you want to animate.  Currently the positioning is based on block layout with the other div, and this is not animating.  But if you update the CSS position yourself, then that transition will animate.  See the below example.

```js
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $("#top").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#bottom").css({ top: '0px' });
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    background-color: yellow !important;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't really help since in the original question the `#bottom` is not positioned absolutely. And in a majority of cases I wouldn't think it would be.